# Next.js Automatic Static Optimization

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I was reading about **Automatic Static Optimization** and I came across this little section that says:

So according to this  [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server)

During prerendering, the router's query object will be empty since we do not have query information to provide during this phase. After hydration, Next.js will trigger an update to your application to provide the route parameters in the query object.

> Note: Parameters added with dynamic routes to a page that's using
> getStaticProps will always be available inside the query object.

The first paragraph says that the query object will be empty but the NOTE section says that it will always have available the parameters.

So what rule applies here?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @shanemacbride To understand what the doc means

Answer (score 0):

This comes from the caveats section  of dynamic-routes in the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#caveats)

> Pages that are statically optimized by Automatic Static Optimization will be hydrated without their route parameters provided, i.e query will be an empty object (`{}`).

> After hydration, Next.js will trigger an update to your application to provide the route parameters in the query object.

And also have a look at this [issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/10521#issuecomment-586322419) where the exact behavior of the `query` object being empty before hydration is discussed as correct behavior by the co-author.